# Hangman Python Game Index Error in For Loop with the Lists

Tags: python, string, list

Okay, I am working on a homework assignment to build a hangman game in python. So far, it was going well untill I get this annoying error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/Users/Toly/Downloads/ps2 6/ps2_hangman.py", line 82, in <module>
    if (remLetters[i] == userGuess):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Here is my code:

```
    # 6.00 Problem Set 3
    # 
    # Hangman
    #


    # -----------------------------------
    # Helper code
    # (you don't need to understand this helper code)
    import random
    import string
    import time

    WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

    def load_words():
        print "Loading word list from file..."
        # inFile: file
        inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'r', 0)
        # line: string
        line = inFile.readline()
        # wordlist: list of strings
        wordlist = string.split(line)
        print "  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded."
        return wordlist

    def choose_word(wordlist):
        """
        wordlist (list): list of words (strings)

        Returns a word from wordlist at random
        """
        return random.choice(wordlist)

    wordlist = load_words()

    blankword="_ "
    word=random.choice (wordlist)    
    remLetters = string.lowercase
    remGuesses = 8 #starting number of guesses
    remWord=len(word)

    #makes a blank with the length of the word
    print "Welcome to Hangman"
    time.sleep(1)
    print
    print "Your word is", remWord,"letters long."
    print
    time.sleep (1)

    while (remGuesses != 0 or blankword != word):
        remBlankword=len(blankword)


 remWordDoubled=remWord*2
    while (remWordDoubled!=len(blankword)):
        blankword=blankword + "_ "
    print blankword
    print
    print "You have",remGuesses," guesses left."
    print
    time.sleep(1)
    userGuess= str(raw_input ("Guess a letter:"))
    print
    if (userGuess in word):
        print "Excellent guess!"

    else:
       print "Bad Guess"
       remGuesses=remGuesses-1
    for i in range (1, len(remLetters)):
       if (remLetters[i] == userGuess):
            remLetters = remLetters[0:i] + remLetters[i+1:len(remLetters)]

    print remLetters


if (remGuesses == 0):
    print
    print "Sorry, you died! Ha, sucks!"
    print
    print
    time.sleep (1)
    print "End of Game"


if (blankword == word):
    print
    print "Congradulations! You won!"
    print
    time.sleep(1)
    print 
    print
    print
    print "End of Game"
```

Comment: FWIW, python doesn't require parentheses on control structures - `if (remGuesses == 0):` is less pythonic than `if remGuesses == 0:`

Comment: Since no one else has mentioned - what's with using the `string` module for `.split()` - that's long since deprecated - and I don't see any advantage in opening the wordlist as unbuffered either...

Answer (score 2):

You first get the range of indices in `remLetters`, but if the letter == `userGuess`, then you remove one letter out of `remLetters`. Meaning that now the largest index in `remLetters` is 1 less than it was before.  When you try to index the highest number returned by your range, you are now out of bounds and so you get an `IndexError`.

Something like this is probably what you're looking for:

```
remLetters = ''.join(x for x in remLetters if x != userGuess)
```

Or:

```
try:
    idx = remLetters.index(userGuess)
    remLetters = remLetters[:idx] + remLetters[idx+1:]
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: your second idea didnt work, and i didnt get the first one's logic at all

Comment: @user1624992 -- I'm guessing it threw a ValueError because the userGuess wasn't in `remLetters`.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing the string `remLetters` in the loop, making it shorter. So you end up with an index that lies beyond the length of `remLetters`:

```
for i in range (1, len(remLetters)):
   if (remLetters[i] == userGuess):
        remLetters = remLetters[0:i] + remLetters[i+1:len(remLetters)]
```

Use `.index()` instead to find matches:

```
while userGuess in remLetters:
    i = remLetters.index(userGuess)
    remLetters = remLeters[:i] + remLetters[i+1:]
```

Comment: but how would i use the .index ()

Comment: how would i use .index though